# Redirecionamento para outra pagina

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tenho um Dropzone.js e após arrastar e soltar um arquivo no meu html gostaria de receber um redirecionamento para outra pagina, gostaria de saber como proceder, já tentei algumas formas e não consegui, se alguém puder me dar uma luz.

**Dropzone.js**

```
function addProgressBar(that, i, index){
    $(that.element).parent()
        .append('<div class="progress progress-'+index+'"></div>')
        .css({'margin': that.options.margin});
    $(".progress-"+index).css({
        width: that.options.progressBarWidth,
        margin: '20px 0 0 0',
    }).append('<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active"></div>').hide();
    $(".progress-" + index).wrap('<div class="extra-progress-wrapper"></div>');
    //$(".progress-" + index).parent().append('<span title="'+that.options.files[i].name+'">'+that.options.files[i].name.trunc(20)+'</span>').css("width", that.options.progressBarWidth);
    if(that.options.showTimer){
        $(".progress-" + index).parent().append('<span style="float:right" class="upload-timer-'+index+'">0</span>');
    }
}

function addFileToBigField(that, i, index){
    $(that.element).parent()
        .append('<div class="progress error-progress-'+index+'"></div>')
        .css('margin', that.options.margin);
    var file = that.options.files[i];
    var fileName = file.name.trunc(25);
    $(".error-progress-"+index).css({
        width: that.options.progressBarWidth,
        margin: '20px 0 0 0'
    }).append('<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped" style="width:100%">Arquivo muito grande ('+humanFileSize(file.size)+')</div>');
    $(".error-progress-" + index).wrap('<div class="extra-progress-wrapper"></div>').css("width", that.options.progressBarWidth);
    $(".error-progress-" + index).parent().append('<span title="'+that.options.files[i].name+'">'+fileName+'</span>');
}

function addWrongFileField(that, i, index){
    $(that.element).parent()
        .append('<div class="progress error-progress-'+index+'"></div>')
        .css('margin', that.options.margin);
    var file = that.options.files[i];
    var fileName = file.name.trunc(25);
    var extension = file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    $(".error-progress-"+index).css({
        width: that.options.progressBarWidth,
        margin: '20px 0 0 0'
    }).append('<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped" style="width:100%">File type ('+extension+') is not allowed</div>');
    $(".error-progress-" + index).wrap('<div class="extra-progress-wrapper"></div>').css("width", that.options.progressBarWidth);
    $(".error-progress-" + index).parent().append('<span title="'+that.options.files[i].name+'">'+fileName+'</span>');
}

function showTooltip(){
    $("span").tooltip({
        open: function(event, ui){
            ui.tooltip.css("max-width", '100%');
        }
    });
}

function checkFileType(that, file){
    if (!file.type && file.size%4096 === 0) return false;
    if(that.options.allowedFileTypes == '*') return true;

    var extension = file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

    var allowedTypes = that.options.allowedFileTypes.replace(' ', '').split(",");
    var allowedTypesLower = [];

    for (var i = allowedTypes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(allowedTypes[i].indexOf(".") != -1){
            if(file.type.match(allowedTypes[i]) !== null) return true;
        }
        allowedTypesLower.push(allowedTypes[i].toLowerCase());
    }

    if($.inArray(extension, allowedTypesLower) != -1) return true;

    return false;
}
var validAmount  = function(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
};

var parsableUnit = function(u) {
    return u.match(/\D*/).pop() === u;
};

var incrementBases = {
  2: [
    [["B", "Bytes"], 1],
    [["Kb"], 128],
    [["k", "K", "kb", "KB", "KiB", "Ki", "ki"], 1024],
    [["Mb"], 131072],
    [["m", "M", "mb", "MB", "MiB", "Mi", "mi"], Math.pow(1024, 2)],
    [["Gb"], 1.342e+8],
    [["g", "G", "gb", "GB", "GiB", "Gi", "gi"], Math.pow(1024, 3)],
    [["Tb"], 1.374e+11],
    [["t", "T", "tb", "TB", "TiB", "Ti", "ti"], Math.pow(1024, 4)],
    [["Pb"], 1.407e+14],
    [["p", "P", "pb", "PB", "PiB", "Pi", "pi"], Math.pow(1024, 5)],
    [["Eb"], 1.441e+17],
    [["e", "E", "eb", "EB", "EiB", "Ei", "ei"], Math.pow(1024, 6)]
  ],
  10: [
    [["B", "Bytes"], 1],
    [["Kb"], 125],
    [["k", "K", "kb", "KB", "KiB", "Ki", "ki"], 1000],
    [["Mb"], 125000],
    [["m", "M", "mb", "MB", "MiB", "Mi", "mi"], 1.0e+6],
    [["Gb"], 1.25e+8],
    [["g", "G", "gb", "GB", "GiB", "Gi", "gi"], 1.0e+9],
    [["Tb"], 1.25e+11],
    [["t", "T", "tb", "TB", "TiB", "Ti", "ti"], 1.0e+12],
    [["Pb"], 1.25e+14],
    [["p", "P", "pb", "PB", "PiB", "Pi", "pi"], 1.0e+15],
    [["Eb"], 1.25e+17],
    [["e", "E", "eb", "EB", "EiB", "Ei", "ei"], 1.0e+18]
  ]
};


function filesizeParser(input) {
  var options = arguments[1] || {};
  var base = parseInt(options.base || 2);

  var parsed = input.toString().match(/^([0-9\.,]*)(?:\s*)?(.*)$/);
  var amount = parsed[1].replace(',','.');
  var unit = parsed[2];

  var validUnit = function(sourceUnit) {
    return sourceUnit === unit;
  };

  if (!validAmount(amount) || !parsableUnit(unit)) {
    throw 'Can\'t interpret ' + (input || 'a blank string');
  }
  if (unit === '') return amount;

  var increments = incrementBases[base];
  for (var i = 0; i < increments.length; i++) {
    var _increment = increments[i];

    if (_increment[0].some(validUnit)) {
      return amount * _increment[1];
    }
  }

  throw unit + ' doesn\'t appear to be a valid unit';
}

function checkFileSize(that, file){

    return file.size < filesizeParser(that.options.maxFileSize);
}

function humanFileSize(bytes) {
    var thresh = 1024;
    if(Math.abs(bytes) < thresh) {
        return bytes + ' Bytes';
    }
    var units = ['KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
    var u = -1;
    do {
        bytes /= thresh;
        ++u;
    } while(Math.abs(bytes) >= thresh && u < units.length - 1);
    return bytes.toFixed(1)+' '+units[u];
}
String.prototype.trunc = String.prototype.trunc || function(n){
      return this.length>n ? this.substr(0,n-1)+'&hellip;' : this;
};

// A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
// preventing against multiple instantiations
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
            new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
    });
};
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['files']['name'][0])){
    echo "error";
}
echo "success";
```

?>

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $("div#drop").dropzone({
    url: 'upload.php'      })
</script>


    <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-body">    
            <div align="center">

                <div class="dropzone" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como e onde você instancia o Dropzone? Como e onde você chama o upload.php?

Comment: Coloca um `header("location: pagina.php")` na onde vc esta imprimindo "success"

Comment: @LeonardoBarros fiz alteração e coloquei as respostas da sua pergunta.

Comment: @MBoss infelizmente não me redirecionou para lugar nenhum.

Comment: @GuilhermePalange Quando vc solta um arquivo no drop zone ele chama o upload.php correto?

Comment: @MBoss ,Chama sim, ele faz upload para a pasta correta, porém não me apresenta mensagem alguma nem me redireciona para a pagina seguinte.

Comment: @GuilhermePalange Esse seu `if` no arquivo Upload.php deve estar incorreto então. Pois ele iria imprimir "error" ou "success".